# change the active list when scrolling navbar

Tags: javascript, frontend, navbar, nav, onscroll

I'am trying to makes my navbar moves between sections will I scroll down.

I tried to makes it with JS but I cant makes it work
it is change the active class when I click with event listener but I can't make it work when I scroll

Thanks for any help

here is my js code

```
let section = document.querySelectorAll('section')
let lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
function activeLink(){
    lists.forEach((item) =>
    item.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
}
lists.forEach((item) =>
item.addEventListener('click',activeLink));

window.onscroll = () =>{
  section.forEach(sec =>{
    let top = window.scrollY;
    let offset = sec.offsetTop;
    let height = sec.offsetHeight;
    let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

    if(top >= offset && top < offset + height){
      lists.forEach(sec =>{
        activeLink;
      })
    }
  })
};
```

and this is my html

```
<nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="list active">
                <a href="#home">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#about">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">About Me</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#working">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="newspaper-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Working</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="code-slash-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Learned</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#contact">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="chatbox-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question right but to me it sounds like a fixed navbar, isn't it? Why not just set `position: fixed` ?

Comment: it is on position: fixed , I try to makes my navbar moves between sections while I am scrolling

Comment: fixed means it is relative to your viewport, so it should automatically move between sections. Maybe you can provide your HTML too, so one can follow better.

Comment: I added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you're not calling the "activeLink" function correctly.

```
 if(top >= offset && top < offset + height){
  lists.forEach(sec =>{
    activeLink;
  })
}
```

If you add the parentheses, then it'll work and throw an error due to the "this" keyword which refers to the window object in this case.

To work, in the "onScroll" handler, you can replace your code with this piece:

```
if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
    lists.forEach((item) => {
        item.classList.remove('active');
        if(item.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href') == '#' + id){
            item.classList.add('active');
        }
     });            
}
```

Of course, your aim will be not to duplicate your code. So, we can first select the target like that:

```
const target = document.querySelector(`[href='#${id}']`).parentElement;
activeLink(target);
```

Passing it to the "activeLink" function directly will lead you to check the coming parameter if it is the "click event" or the list item and handles both cases. instead,  you can edit your handler code like this:

```
lists.forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener('click', function(){
     activeLink(this);
  }));
```

And this is the "activeLink" function code in the final state:

```
function activeLink(li) {
    lists.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'));
    li.classList.add('active');
}
```

**Here is the code snippet for this:**

```js
let section = document.querySelectorAll('section');
        let lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
        function activeLink(li) {
            lists.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'));
            li.classList.add('active');
        }
        lists.forEach((item) =>
            item.addEventListener('click', function(){
                activeLink(this);
            }));

        window.onscroll = () => {
            section.forEach(sec => {
                let top = window.scrollY;
                let offset = sec.offsetTop;
                let height = sec.offsetHeight;
                let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

                if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
                    const target = document.querySelector(`[href='#${id}']`).parentElement;
                    activeLink(target);
                }
            })
        };
```

```css
.sec {
            height: 500px;
        }

        nav {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .active a {
            color: palevioletred;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="list active">
                <a href="#home">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#about">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">About Me</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#working">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="newspaper-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Working</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#Learned">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="code-slash-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Learned</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#contact">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="chatbox-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="title">Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="sec" style="background-color: beige;" id="home"></section>
    <section class="sec" style="background-color: yellow;" id="about"></section>
    <section class="sec" style="background-color: orange;" id="working"></section>
    <section class="sec" style="background-color: orangered;" id="Learned"></section>
    <section class="sec" style="background-color: olive;" id="contact"></section>
```

Comment: First of all , Thank you very much for answer and explaination
I copy and paste it and its still the same not worked on scroll but work on click

Comment: its wasnt work for me beacause I had another onScroll function on my code so I
merged them and now its works , Thank you